# Arduino Bluepill STM32 spi doesn't work

Tags: spi, stm32

Has anyone successfully use SPI1 of those pins?

```
SCLK -> PB3 
SDIO -> PB5 
SDO -> PB4 
MISO CS -> PA15
```

I've tried to use another side of SPI1 pins on the other sides of the board (PA4, 5, 6, 7) and i can successfully communicate with
[image]

Comment: Arduino and STM32 Blue pill are not the same, they are different platforms. And you need to supply more details, like the complete code.

Comment: i used the stm32arduino core , so i will perform like arduino and the code is very simple just spi output to sensor its not responsing at all until i switch the pin it will work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you use the SPI object. If you use the SPI object directly like what Arduino Uno without creating an instance object, the SPI construct will default to the PA4 - PA7, see the [default pins definition](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/main/variants/STM32F1xx/F103C8T_F103CB(T-U)/variant_PILL_F103Cx.h#L104-L113) and [default Class construct](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/main/libraries/SPI/src/SPI.cpp#L25) of Blue Pill.

For STM32 Arduino Core (Stm32duino), there are four STM32 Arduino Core specific APIs for configure the alternative SPI pins.

```
void setMISO(uint32_t miso)
void setMOSI(uint32_t mosi)
void setSCLK(uint32_t sclk)
void setSSEL(uint32_t ssel)
```

These **must** be called before the `SPI.begin()`.

Another alternative way of using the alternative SPI pins is to create an SPI object and pass-in the pin assignments like this:

```
#include <SPI.h>

SPIClass mySPI(PB5, PB4, PB3, PB15); //mosi, miso, sclk, ssel
```

See the [alternative construct](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/blob/main/libraries/SPI/src/SPI.cpp#L46-L52) API, and further information on STM32duino [wiki](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32/wiki/API#spi) page.

Comment: Thank a lot , you had no idea how many hours i waste on this thing :)